# What event marks a Validator as selected for next session

Tags: polkadot-js, kusama, validator, session

Under Network > Staking > Targets we can see some validators are selected for the `next session / active set.`
[image]

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama-rpc.polkadot.io#/staking/targets

What event is this on the blockchain?

Can I listen for this, e.g. using rpc/js api?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an even in the Staking pallet: `StakersElected`, however this event does not itself contain all the new stakers that were selected since that list can be large, and just as easily queried if needed.

So once you see the `StakersElected` event, you can simply do the following query `electionsPhragmen > Members` to get the list of the new validators:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shawn for naming the Event.

I found the documentation here:
https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events/#stakerselected

And here is the code to listen for events:
https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/system-events